# Bash Script To Change Curly Brace Style

Tags: linux, bash, sed, curly-braces

I have a CSS file and a PHP file that I received from an overseas outsource partner. He prefers curly braces on a new line, while I am rather Old School and prefer the curly brace on the same line as the declaration. How can I use Bash and/or sed or other command-line tools to revert curly braces from this new style and into this older style?

**EDIT**: Someone wanted to see an example. Okay, here goes:

NEW SCHOOL STYLE I DO NOT LIKE

```
body 
{
padding:4px;
margin:3px;
}
```

OLD SCHOOL I PREFER

```
body {
padding:4px;
margin:3px;
}
```

NEW SCHOOL STYLE I DO NOT LIKE

```
function foo() 
{
// some code here
}
```

OLD SCHOOL STYLE I PREFER

```
function foo() {
// some code here
}
```

Comment: Please give sample input and sample output

Comment: Nope not kidding, if you've ever seen [this image](http://keremkosaner.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/softwaredevelopment.gif) you'll know why

Comment: You don't believe in indentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 sed 'N;/\n{/s// {/;P;D' file.css
```

#### Input

```
$ cat file.css
body
{
background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
h1
{
color:orange;
text-align:center;
}
p
{
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size:20px;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ sed 'N;/\n{/s// {/;P;D' file.css
body {
background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
h1 {
color:orange;
text-align:center;
}
p {
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A start might be:

```
sed 'N;/\n{/s/\n/ /;P;D' inputfile
```

If a line begins with a curly brace, it will be appended to the previous line (with an added space).