# Bash script to change curly brace style regardless of whitespace

Tags: bash, sed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521618/bash-script-to-change-curly-brace-style) question/answer is nearly exactly what I want to do.

However, I wish to change the `sed` line to turn something like this:

```
                                if(something) 
                                {
 // whitespace                        // code in braces of this style
                                }
```

into something like this:

```
                                if(something) {
 // whitespace                        // code in braces of some other style
                                }
```

i.e. I want the `sed` line to format code that has been indented to the right of the page too.

I'm new to `sed` so don't know about how you're meant to do this.

Here's the current `sed` line: `sed 'N;/\n{/s// {/;P;D' $file`

Thank you :).

Comment: I refuse to help because the silly braces are actually the nice ones.

Comment: Edited question :P.  We have some general coding standards here and we just all write in the second way for consistency.  We could just as easily all write in the other way but what I don't want is some people writing in one way and others in the other way!

Comment: For readability I would say that the first style is better. Offtopic though.

Comment: From my experience, the second is most common now though.  You're right though, off-topic :P!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does just adding " *" help?

```
sed 'N;/\n *{/s// {/;P;D'
```

Comment: I knew it would just be one character :P.  Thanks mate.

Comment: @alemaster: They are two, actually ;-)